# apache redirect HTTPS to canonical HTTPS

Tags: apache, lets-encrypt

I want all access to my website to be forced to HTTPS (https://support.google.com/webmasters/answer/6073543?hl=en).

I also want to force canonical www URL access (https://www.yes-www.org/why-use-www/)

I am attempting to do so according to Apache recommendations using the Redirect directive https://wiki.apache.org/httpd/RedirectSSL and https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/rewrite/remapping.html#canonicalhost

I have a valid lets-encrypt certificate which has both www and the naked domain.

I have configured *:80 and *:443 VirtualHost redirects.  /etc/httpd/conf.d/www.example.com.conf:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
  ServerName  www.example.com
  ServerAlias     example.com
  Redirect permanent / https://www.example.com
</VirtualHost>

<VirtualHost *:443>
  ServerName  example.com
  SSLEngine on
  SSLCertificateFile    /etc/letsencrypt/live/www.example.com/cert.pem
  SSLCertificateKeyFile /etc/letsencrypt/live/www.example.com/privkey.pem
  SSLCACertificateFile  /etc/letsencrypt/live/www.example.com/fullchain.pem
  Redirect permanent / https://www.example.com
</VirtualHost>

<VirtualHost *:443>
  ServerName www.example.com
  SSLEngine on
  SSLCertificateFile    /etc/letsencrypt/live/www.example.com/cert.pem
  SSLCertificateKeyFile /etc/letsencrypt/live/www.example.com/privkey.pem
  SSLCACertificateFile  /etc/letsencrypt/live/www.example.com/fullchain.pem
  DocumentRoot "/var/www/html/www.example.com"
</VirtualHost>

<Directory "/var/www/html/www.example.com">
  Order allow,deny
  Allow from all
</Directory>
```

All works well if I specify base URL (example.com, www.example.com, https://example.com, etc).  However, if I specify a page on the naked HTTPS request the redirect eats the root slash (https://example.com/index.html becomes https://www.example.comindex.html).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

RedirectMatch appears to solve the problem similar to the Rewrite suggested by ivanivan.  Changing Redirect line in *:443 VHost section to the following seems to fix the issue:

```
RedirectMatch permanent ^/?(.*) https://www.example.com/$1
```

I still don't understand why simple Redirect doesn't work with HTTPS.

As an aside, https://salferrarello.com/chrome-clear-redirect-cache/ was useful disabling Redirect caching in Chrome during testing.

Answer (score 0):

I do it with the following for all non-ssl to ssl -

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
  ServerName example.org
  ServerAlias www.example.org
  RewriteEngine on
  RewriteRule ^/(.*)$ https://www.example.org/$1 [R,L]
</VirtualHost>
```

Slighly different should do the same for `https://example.org` only redirecting to `www.example.org`

```
<VirtualHost your.ip.add.ress:443>
  ServerName example.org
  RewriteEngine on
  RewriteRule ^/(.*)$ https://www.example.org/$1 [R,L]

  *snip*  
  Normal SSL certificate/key stuff goes here
  *snip*

</VirtualHost>
```

Comment: I am not opposed to Rewrite, but the Apache documentation explicitly recommends Redirect instead.  See link in OP.